# Diagnosing strange lag/catchup or freezing behaviors on my new Laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, cpu, freeze

I've been noticing strange freezes, lags, and crashes, although not too often.  Here's my setup:

**Dell inspiron i7559, as purchased**:

- Intel i7 6700HQ 2.6 GHz processor (officially goes up past 3 on turbo, but I don't know how to check if that's actually working)
- 1 TB HDD with 8 GB embedded flash cache
- 8 GB RAM
- GTX 960M with 4GB RAM

**And upgrades which I installed myself**:

- Additional 8GB of RAM
- Additional 500 GB SSD (The software provided by Samsung was used to make this the boot device.)

**Additional connected hardware**:

- Dell 24 inch S2415H monitor
- Wireless Mouse/Keyboard Combo via USB (both of these were plug and play)

There are a few symptoms I'm trying to diagnose:
1) A programs seem to freeze for 10-15 seconds when lots of programs are open, and then sort of flash forward, playing all those frames really fast.  This happened at least twice.
2) When done with the computer the day this happened, shutting down triggered a blue screen of death.  BlueScreenView shows me ntoskrnl.exe is the "cause."

In attempt to research what might have caused a processor hang like this, I found people mentioning a [hanging bug with Intel Skylake processors](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3021023/hardware/how-to-test-your-pc-for-the-skylake-bug.html).  I ran the recommended test program, [prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/), for around 10 minutes (not very long, I know) and the only thing I noticed was that the laptop got louder.

Further, I tried to run the Windows Memory Diagnostic tool, and got the following error:
[image: Missing memtest.EFI]

What is wrong with this computer?  Am I following all the wrong diagnostic passages?  What should I be doing to actually figure out what caused those hangs and blue screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but here are a few of things you might try...

1. Go to Power Options in Control Panel, try selecting the "High
   Performance"  plan. (Open Control Panel > Search "Power Options" in the top right > Change Power Plan to "High Performance")
2. Make sure you are using "legit" dell RAM (fakes might not work properly)
3. Run an anti-malware scan using trustworthy anti-malware software (like malware bytes). A virus or something could be using up your computer resources.

If nothing else works, you should probably revert the PC to its "factory" condition, that is replace the old RAM and HDD. And continue from there.

(I looked at the hanging bug you mentioned, I personally have a i7 6700k that I use for video rendering (my cpu goes up to 90%+ usage) and I've never had any issues)

Hope this was Helpful :D

Comment: legit dell ram?  What a scam!

Comment: I gotta agree, legit dell ram is hilariously expensive. Who knows, could be the issue, I've found dead ram sticks before. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯